# Запрос INSERT в YII

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Можно ли проверить значения, которые передает запрос INSERT в YII? Дело в том, что при добавлении записи вылетает след. ошибка:

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить
> SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add
> or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`eshop`.`tbl_goods`,
> CONSTRAINT `fkGoodsCategory` FOREIGN
> KEY (`category`) REFERENCES
> `tbl_category` (`title`) ON UPDATE
> CASCADE). The SQL statement executed
> was: INSERT INTO `tbl_goods` (`title`,
> `category`, `quo`, `price`,
> `description`, `status`) VALUES (:yp0,
> :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5)

Такая ошибка выходит когда вводишь значение внешнего ключа, которое отсутствует в справочнике. Я полагаю что yii передает не правильное значение из-за не правльной кодировки в каком-то файле. 
**С командной строки все работает нормально.** Поэтому мой вопрос: Можно ли проверить значения, которые передает запрос INSERT ?

Всех заранее благодарю.

Comment: псотавьте себе дебагер и нацчитесь им пользоваться. В php используется Xdebug

Answer (score 1):

Для отображения параметров в запросе используйте в конфиге параметр enableParamLogging со значением true

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
    ),
```

В результате запросы отображаются следующим образом

```
SELECT * FROM `items` `t` WHERE cid = :cid AND status = :status AND iid != :iid ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :limit. Bound with :cid='5', :status='on', :iid='1', :limit=3
```